Unable to properly encrypt data using rsa public key in Swift
Encryption Stack Overflow Question
I have a private/public key pair generated by openssl with aes256 and 2048 but encryption. On the server, I am able to encrypt and decrypt data using openssl with the private and public keys with no issue.
I have not been successful in encrypting data in Swift at all. I have tried a few methods and the data appears to be encrypted but when I try to decrypt on the server, it keeps telling me
rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater than mod len:crypto\rsa\rsa_ossl.c:407

I haven't been able to find any really good resources on how to do this in Swift but here's what I have; (Ignore the force unwraps. They are just there for testing)

Create a SecKey from the public key;

    private func createSecKey() -> SecKey {
        // Remove headers and footers from the PEM, leaving us with DER encoded data split by new lines
        [
            "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----", "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----",
            "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
        ].forEach { publicKey = publicKey.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: "") }

        // Construct DER data from the remaining PEM data
        let der = Data(base64Encoded: publicKey, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        let attributes: [String: Any] = [
            String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            String(kSecAttrKeyClass): kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
            String(kSecAttrKeySizeInBits): der.count * 8
        ]
        let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(der as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, nil)!
        return key
    }


Encrypt Data;

    private func encryptMessageData(secKey: SecKey, message: String) {
        print(aesKeyPair)
        // An example message to encrypt
        let messageData = message.data(using: .utf8)!
            
        // Perform the actual encryption
        let encryptedMessage = SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(secKey, .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256, messageData as CFData, nil)! as Data
        print("=====Encrypted Message Below=====")
        print(encryptedMessage.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined())
        self.encryptedAESKey.text = cipherText.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        
}

I tried encoding the encrypted response to base64 and decrypting that;
let base64Data = encryptedMessage.base64EncodedData(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)

When I try to decrypt on the server;
openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey tvde_private.pem -in message.decoded > message.txt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep

That’s where I get
Public Key operation error
501A0000:error:02000079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error:crypto\rsa\rsa_oaep.c:314:


I don’t’ know if that brings me any closer to my goal or not>
Now, I think the issue is during the data encryption;
        let encryptedMessage = SecKeyCreateEncryptedData(secKey, .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256, messageData as CFData, nil)! as Data


I don’t really know which algorithm to choose here. I’ve tried  .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256 and .rsaEncryptionOAEPSHA256AESGCM but I honestly dont’ know what all of the algorithms listed in the SecKeyAlgorithm are and the key I’ve generated was jsut done using aes256 and 2048 bit encryption.
Doesn’t anyone have any suggestions?

Of course after spending hours on this an not coming up with anything, I can across a different SO post that helped me: openssl padding error. I needed to change the algorithm to .rsaEncryptionPKCS1 for encryption. I then base64 encode it, fire it off and am able to decrypt on the server.
